Did Gauss criticize cardinals?
In a well-known passage, Gauss criticized the use of infinity in mathematics in the following terms:

I protest first of all against the use of an infinite quantity as a completed one, which is never permissible in mathematics. The infinite is only a façon de parler, where one is really speaking of limits to which certain ratios come as close as one likes while others are allowed to grow without restriction.

This has often been interpreted by historians as rejection of "completed" infinity, also known as actual infinity (and contrasted with potential infinity).  Actual infinity is considered to have been "tamed" by Cantor, who based his theory of infinite ordinals and cardinals on the idea of actual infinity.  Hilbert famously referred to such a framework as a "Cantorian paradise".
However, other historians give a different interpretation of Gauss' passage. Waterhouse points out in

WILLIAM C. WATERHOUSE, GAUSS ON INFINITY, Historia Mathematica 6 (1979), 430-436

that the context of Gauss's passage is a criticism of a contemporary mathematician's attempted proof of the parallel postulate, using the idea of a circle of a radius of infinite magnitude.  Accordingly, it is not infinite cardinals but rather infinite magnitudes that are rejected by Gauss.  Such infinite magnitudes were formalized in nonstandard analysis, and can be called infinite ringinals (because they are elements of a ring such as the ring of integers), to contrast them with Cantorian infinities.
This leads us to the following question: Did Gauss criticize infinite cardinals or infinite ringinals?
The question was asked at Philosophy SE without generating substantive feedback.
Moore notes the following:

"Waterhouse [1979] has noted in this journal, correctly, that Gauss’s remarks were not directed against set
theory, which in any case did not exist at that time. But Cantor saw Gauss’s remarks as aimed against the actual
infinite, etc."

See Moore, Gregory H.$\;$
Hilbert on the infinite: the role of set theory in the evolution of Hilbert's thought.
Historia Math. 29 (2002), no. 1, 40–64.
In more detail, Lipschitz understood Cantor as interpreting the Gaussian passage as opposition to actual infinity (i.e., completed infinite collections).  Waterhouse argues that Lipschitz's comment is the source of the commonly found opinion that Gauss opposed actual infinity (as opposed to potential infinity; both of these are Aristotelian notions).  The question is whether in the quoted passage, Gauss opposed (A) actual infinite collections or (B) infinite magnitudes.  In modern mathematics, these are formalized respectively by (A) cardinals and (B) nonstandard numbers (which can be referred to as "infinite ringinals" because they are elements of a ring).
It should be noted that the existence of infinite cardinals is, mathematically speaking, "transverse" to the existence of "infinite ringinals"; see e.g., Enayat's answer.  Historically, Leibniz used infinite magnitudes (that he referred to as infinita terminata) but rejected completed infinities that he referred to as "infinite wholes".
Note. User Conifold raised an interesting point in the comments.
He seems to claim that Proclus used the term "magnitude" to refer to
an infinite collection, and applied the distinction
potential/completed to it.  That may be a difficulty for the
distinction between magnitude and multitude.  But Proclus did not
write in English.  One would have to look up the Greek term he used,
and explore in what sense that particular term was used at the time.
Also, why should we compare the attitude of Gauss to that of Proclus,
rather than to that of Leibniz?  A straightforward calculation would
reveal that Leibniz is somewhat closer to Gauss than Proclus.
Leibniz's distinction between infinita terminata and infinita
interminata seems to contradict Conifold's claim that the distinction
magnitude/multitude was still inconceivable in Gauss's time (and was
allegedly introduced by Cantor?).  Furthermore, the Leibnizian
distinction was stated in geometric terms: unbounded infinity
(infinitum interminatum) was an unbounded infinite line, whereas
bounded infinity was a segment between infinitely removed endpoints
(thus "bounded" on both sides).  Conifold is encouraged to elaborate
on his interesting comment in the form of an answer.

Cantor was 10 year old in 1855, the year of Gauss' death. I do not think the concept of cardinals existed before Cantor's work.

I responded in the body of the question. @MoisheKohan

Aristotelian objections to infinite magnitudes were taken to apply to infinite numbers just the same. Proclus writes, for example, in his commentary on Euclid: "magnitude is infinitely divisible, but not into an infinite number of parts. The latter statement makes an infinite number actual, the former merely potential; the latter assigns existence to the infinite, the other only genesis." Later part-whole objections are easily converted both ways via Euclid's use of segments for numbers. Gauss's protestation, as that of others, simply does not lend itself to modern distinctions.

What I gather from an article by Karasmanis, who quotes the relevant
passage from Proclus, is that the Greeks thought of mathematics as
composed of two separate parts: discrete (numbers) and continuous
(magnitudes).  So when Proclus uses the term "magnitude" he is merely
referring to the continuum (or "extension" as some authors called it
in the 17/18 centuries).  This seems to undermine Conifold's claim.  @Conifold

Sadly Lipschitz's letter is lost so we don't actually have access to his precise claims (see "Briefe"  p. 149). That said I think reading Cantor's response in detail is very helpful, because Cantor understands Gauss's point in Gauss's context.
Schumacher had made an argument that used infinity as a fixed point and he ends up with a wrong conclusion. Gauss proceeds to show that you can use the notion of infinity but with the proper care. Cantor describes this as follows:

In diesen bei den Sätzen ist Falsches mit Wahrem durcheinander
gemengt;

So Cantor says that there is truth and error intermixed in Gauss's statement. He proceeds to explain.

was das Wahre daran betrifft, so finden Sie es fast mit
denselben Worten auch von Leibniz (Erdmann pag.436) angesprochen. Ich
citire diese Stelle in der Arbeit "Grundlagen" auf pag. 17 vollständig
[[W], S. 179]. Die Bedeutung davon ist einfach die, dass man es in der
Differential und Integralrechnung niemals mit unendlichkleinen oder
unendlichgrossen Grössen zu thun hat, die man sich vollendet d. h.
unveränderlich vorstellen möchte, sondern immer nur mit beliebig oder
wie man sich auch ausdrückt unendlich klein resp. unendlich gross
werdenden Grössen. Gauss und Leibniz protestiren also hier, und mit
vollem Recht, gegen die fehlerhafte, widerspruchsvolle Vorstellung von
Differentialen, die unendlich klein sind. Sie werden denselben Protest
an verschiedenen Orten meiner Aufsätze ebenfalls finden, beispielsw.
in Annalen Bd.XX, pag.121, Note unten [[W], S.156], wo ich auch auf
Sie mich berufen habe. In den "Grundlagen" formulire ich denselben
Protest, indem ich an verschiedenen Stellen mich gegen die
Verwechslung des Uneigentlich-unendlichen (so nenne ich das
veränderliche Endliche) mit dem Eigentlich-unendlichen (so nenne ich
das bestimmte, das vollendete Unendliche, oder auch das Transfinite,
Überendliche ) ausspreche.

I won't translate the full passage but Cantor actually says he agrees with Gauss's protestation in the context in which Gauss speaks which is the use of infinities in calculus, and he emphasizes that he has made the same objections in his own writing. So in the sense that Gauss has problems with problematic uses of infinity in geometric arguments of Schumacher, Gauss is correct and in agreement with Cantor, according to Cantor.
However then Cantor spells out the mistake in Gauss's statement:

Das Irrthümliche in jener Gauss'schen Stelle besteht darin, dass er
sagt, das Vollendetunendliche könne nicht Gegenstand mathematischer
Betrachtungen werden; dieser Irrthum hängt mit dem andern Irrthum
zusammen, dass er (übrigens gleichfalls in Übereinstimmung mit
Descartes, Leibniz und vielen anderen Vorgängern, wie Sie aus meinen
Citaten auf pag.12 und 16 meiner "Grundlagen" ersehen) das Vollendetunendliche mit dem Absoluten, Göttlichen identificirt, wogegen ich in § 5 und in § 7 derselben Schrift meinerseits protestiren musste.

My translation (abridged):

The mistake in the passage of Gauss is, that the infinite could not be subject of mathematical investigation. This misconception is connected with the misconception that identifies the completed infinite with the Absolute, Divine, against which I have already protested in my writing.

My own personal view is that the latter part is a strong reading of Gauss that is not actually fully justified from Gauss's own expression.
In fact the concluding section of Gauss's letter containing his protestation reads:

In der Bildersprache des Unendlichen würde man also sagen müssen, dass
die Peripherien zweier unendlichen Kreise, deren Halbmesser um eine
endliche Grösse verschieden sind, sel_bst um eine Grösse verschieden
sind, die zu ihnen ein endliches Verhältniss hat.

Gauss had just demonstrated the use of infinity in a legitimate way and recapitulates the fact that starting from finite, going through the infinite one returns to finite result. To this he then says:

Hierin ist aber nichts Widersprechendes, wenn der endliche Mensch sich nicht vermisst
etwas Unendliches als etwas Gebenes und von ihm mit seiner gewohnten
Anschauung zu Umspannendes betrachten zu wollen. Sie sehen, dass hier
in der That der Fragepunkt unmittelbar an die Metaphysik streift.

My translation:

Therein is nothing contradictory, when a finite human does not get
lost to take something infinite as given and inspect it with familiar
perspectives circumscriptions. You see, that the point in question
immediately touches upon the metaphysical.

Does Gauss really talk here about the Absolute, or Divine? It is possible but in my view unlikely. Rather I read this passage as suggesting that through there are philosophical questions regarding the use of the infinite in arguments, it can work out. Regardless it is worth to point out that there may well be a difference between Gauss's intent here versus Cantor's reading of it.
It is likely that Cantor really was already set in an argument against that theistic barrier before given that his Grundlagen predates and is cited in the letter to Lipschitz, and he simply slots in Gauss into that line of argument and he is not actually responsive to the metaphysics comment in Gauss.
In his Grundlagen &5 he seeks to agree that the divine according to him is indeed cannot be probed, but the absolute infinite can. Cantor is aware of a standing notion of the impossibility of the "absolute infinite". Even years later Cantor would list historical figures and contemporary mathematicians who according to him held these notion in his letter to Hilbert ("Briefe" 27.1.1900) where he also repeats that he sees himself in opposition to the authorities of Gauss and Dedekind, along a long list of others yet unconvinced.
Certainly Cantor seems to view his work as needing a new gap that was not given before and he spends substantial energy to argue for this gap that he then fills.
Certainly according to Cantor pretty much all of his historical predecessors got it wrong in not seeing the possibility of transfinite numbers and in that sense they were "wrong". But Cantor understands in what sense his predecessors were right about their use of infinity, and being aware that Cantor argued for concepts that in some concrete sense was never contemplated by his predecessors complicates interpreting their older position as "rejection" of his. But regardless Cantor clearly held that before him notions like transfinite, cardinality, etc were unthinkable and if we align with Cantor so are notions of nonstandard numbers, "infinite ringinals" etc.

One should look at this from the point of view of mathematical rigour: people had been getting good results in math and physics for centuries before Cantor, but the general method was far from rigorous.  Before Cantor/set theory, one always seemed to need some kind of hand-waiving/appeal to metaphysics in the end. Gauss can be interpreted as rejecting/trying to minimise the latter aspects.

Georg and @Sam, It seems to me that the crucial passage is the one where, after discussing Gauss's use of "infinite magnitudes" in the style of Archimedean exhaustion arguments, Cantor suddenly shift gears and attritubutes to Gauss not just one but two things: (1) opposition to actual infinite collections, and (2) as a reason for the previous item, the position that the theological absolute infinite is unfathomable.  Here item (2) is related to Cantor's concern that his set theory will be rejected for theological reasons, as in the response he received from the Vatican to the effect that ...

... mortal man should stick to finite things, and leave infinity alone (I am obviously paraphrasing, but there is an article by Dauben that deals with this in detail). A modern audience would be less interested in item (2) than in item (1), viz. the switch from infinite magnitudes to actual infinite sets. As is well known, these are "transverse" mathematical issues. For example, the traditional non-infinitesimal approach to the foundations of analysis uses infinite sets but not infinite magnitudes. Conversely, Friedman's proof of conservativity of *PA over PA should the the opposite scenario.

What do you think? Georg and @Sam.

I do agree that Cantor's introduction (2) is a bit of "deus ex machina" that has not much to do with Gauss' writings.  This is (meant to be) implicit in my first comment.

@MikhailKatz Certainly there is no evidence that Gauss thought along distinct notions of infinite magnitudes vs infinite sets and the like. He explicitly mentions a process/limit notion and that all we have. With regards to Cantor it would be nice to see Lipschitz' letter. Does it contain anything more than point out Gauss's quote. If no, it might just that  statements by towering predecessors need to be contended with (no matter how meager in substance) and not really evidence of a substantial structural/foundational dispute.

@MikhailKatz A completely different angle to perhaps understand Gauss's positions is the understanding of misuses/improper uses of infinity in proofs (as he points out to Schumacher). After all already Abel in 1826 discussed the issue in the context of divergent series. I do not know if Gauss knew of Abel's concerns in this direction and if his protestation should be read in this context. Certainly it's temporally close (letter to Schumacher is 1831).

"there is no evidence that Gauss thought along distinct notions of infinite magnitudes vs infinite sets": I would agree that Gauss does not make such a distinction in his letter to Schumacher.  Nonetheless, it seems to me that it is legitimate to ask what notion of infinity Gauss was referring to in his letter to Schumacher, based on the context of the Gauss-Schumacher discussion.  Certainly the notion of infinite magnitudes was familiar to 19th century mathematicians, since it was used already by Leibniz in the 17th and by Euler in the 18th.

Historians that claim that such questions are presentist are merely trying to defend the Weierstrassian paradigm for mathematics that they learned as part of their mathematical training.
